Funds USDT Sent via ERC20 to the Blockchain
I need someone to tell me if any of these statements from my BTC trading account are true?
First background I have an account that I was trying to withdraw funds to my crypto com account connected to my bank account. I have done small amounts before $200-$300 occasionally never had to contend with the 3% ERC20 fee but this time I was shocked when I was withdrawing $1000's and was told by the trading account personnel I needed to pay the 3% before the funds would be released from blockchain to my crypto com account. If I know this upfront I would reduce the total amount!!  Then proceeded to tell me I had 72 hours or I would incur more fees! I believe they not telling me the truth on one aspect they keep saying I would pay based on lets say 250K but I only requested 200K they said "oh lets me readjust that"?? I know once in the blockchain it is there for good no take backs!
a. Is there a 72 hours limit to pay the 3% and are there additional fees if not met the time limit? Also I came and told them no can make a wire transfer ever if then had the funds then they responded "we give you an additional 7days" with a click of their finger!
b. I am assuming once you have place the funds in the Blockchain you can't adjust the amount like they said they did?
It seems they are playing games to me! I asked for a printout of the details of their processing the funds to the blockchain but they said we have that available end of year! But I do now have a time stamp when they sent the transfer! All my correspondence with these people is just text so it is all recorded.

Just remember, there are no limits on blockchains. All these limits, locks, and cooldown periods are enforced by the people you are interacting with. Additionally, any reputable exchange won't lock your funds.

This question is similar to: I got scammed or suspect scam on Ethereum or Uniswap. What to do?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Thank you on the "there are no limits on blockchains" this information is hard to find and useful for negotiations! Will do on the similar post.
